# SQL: Modifying Inner Join to Select One Row

Tags: sql

I have two tables, `A` and `B` that I want to inner join on `location`.  However, for each row in `A`, there are many rows in `B` whose `location` matches.  I want to end up with at most the same number of rows as in `A`.  Specifically, I want to take the row in `B` where `date` is earliest.  Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.location = B.location
```

How would I modify this so that each row in `A` only gets joined with a single row in `B` (using the earliest `date`)?

Attempt:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A 
INNER JOIN B ON A.location = B.location 
             AND B.date = (SELECT MIN(date) FROM B)
```

Is that the right approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ANSI/ISO standard `row_number()` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM A INNER JOIN
     (SELECT B.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY B.location ORDER BY B.date) as seqnum
      FROM B
     ) B
     ON A.location = B.location AND seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TOP(1) * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON
A.LOCATION=B.LOCATION 
ORDER BY B.DATE